# Named sql-query: could not execute native bulk manipulation query (but script works fine when executed directly in DB)

Tags: sql, hibernate, bulk

i'm trying to execute a SQL native script using hibernate sql-query. The script is the following:

```
<sql-query name="setAllColors" >
UPDATE chair
    SET COLOR = 'Grey' WHERE NAME='AustrianWinter';
UPDATE chair
    SET COLOR = 'Brown' WHERE NAME='ItalianSummer';
</sql-query>
```

If i execute this same query in Mysql (it's the DB i'm using) all works fine. If i try to execute it via code, recalling the xml where this query is stored, i get:

```
could not execute native bulk manipulation query
```

THE STRANGE FACT is that if i try to execute just the first update, without the second one, all works fine.
Any idea on how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want simple case as you gave, you can use answer from @Adrian.

BUT -  @Adrian **'In hibernate you can't do that.' -- it's not true.**
it's not hibernate restriction , it's restriction jdbc connection. By default it's not allowed to have  multiple queries. BUT you can set setting database connection property to allow multiple queries, separated by a semi-colon by default.This is additional connection property.

> allowMultiQueries=true
>
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_db?allowMultiQueries=true

with whis option you can execute :

```
<sql-query name="setAllColors" >
UPDATE chair
    SET COLOR = 'Grey' WHERE NAME='AustrianWinter';
UPDATE chair
    SET COLOR = 'Brown' WHERE NAME='ItalianSummer';
</sql-query>
```

---

UPDATE 2:
as you use DriverManagerDataSource , allowMultiQueries it's not a part of connection, you should put it as Properties.

from AbstractDriverBasedDataSource

```
    /**
      * Specify arbitrary connection properties as key/value pairs,     
      * to be passed to the Driver.      
      * <p>Can also contain "user" and "password" properties. However,   
      * any "username" and "password" bean properties specified on this      
      * DataSource will override the corresponding connection properties.    
      * @see java.sql.Driver#connect(String, java.util.Properties)   
     */
    public void setConnectionProperties(Properties connectionProperties) {      
        this.connectionProperties = connectionProperties;   
    }
```

so ,configuration should be:

```
   <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/chairDB"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value="pass123"/>
      <property name="connectionProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="allowMultiQueries">true</pro>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

Comment: Actually this solution is more interesting. But it doesn't seem to work for me.. i changed my hib configuration from <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chairDB</property>    to    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chairDB?allowMultiQueries=true</property>  i made a clean and build and then recalled the query... but still the error was thrown. am i missing something else?

Comment: pls show how you run this query get get it? do you have only one  hib configuration file ?

Comment: I edited the question with more info :) thanks for the support by the way

Comment: you didn't use connection url wtih options.  with datasource you should pass it as part of properties , not as url's part

Comment: i changed it as you said but still is not working... i'm thinking of using just an hib cfg file

Comment: I use it as url as connectiin param n hibernate config.with datasource ill chech in 2 3 hours

Comment: You... actually made my day sir !

Comment: I just check with datasource it also works. But i did it in hibernate5.

Comment: Accepted! Migrating from hibernate 3 to 4 made it all work fine !

Comment: One last question... what if i use hql instead of sql? Would it work? Would the syntax be something like: UPDATE com.myCompany.model.Chair
    SET color = 'Grey' WHERE name='AustrianWinter';
UPDATE com.myCompany.model.Chair
    SET color = 'Brown' WHERE name='ItalianSummer'; and so on? (using the same configuration we set up until now)

Comment: not sure. try it. with hql probably no , due to with sql hibernate just run it , with hql hibernate translate / parse it .

Answer (score 1):

In db works fine because MySQL executes them sequentially.
<s>In hibernate you can't do that</s>. There you have to define each update statement in separate sql-query.

However you can try smth like:

```
UPDATE chair SET color = CASE WHEN NAME='AustrianWinter' THEN 'Grey' ELSE 'Brown' END WHERE NAME IN ('AustrianWinter', 'Brown')
```